# c# running function on form1 from form2

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms, function

This question probably has already been answered, I may be type the wrong question in google, but I want to run the function `time_refresh` that is on form1 and works well from form2. this what I got so far:

**Form1**

```
public void time_refresh()
    {
        run_stop.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.s_update + " " + Properties.Settings.Default.s_update_int;
        run_stop.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    }
```

**Form2**

```
private Main_form_1 form1 = null;
```

and

```
form1.time_refresh();
```

But it get an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Kind of new to c# so any help would be excellent.

Comment: First create the form `form1 = new Main_form_1();` then call the method `form1.time_refresh();`

Comment: @Mario: He probably wants the original form.

Comment: @SLaks Actually, the more I look at the question, the less I understand =) Maybe it's just bad naming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to address this issue is through events.  `Form2` shouldn't be accessing `Form1` directly, it should simply be informing `Form1` that it needs to update itself through an event.

On `Form2` create some event like:

```
public Action event Refresh; //TODO rename as appropriate
```

Then, on `Form2` you can fire that event whenever you want `Form1` to know that it needs to refresh itself:

```
public void OnRefresh()  //call this method to fire the event
{
    if(Refresh != null)
        Refresh();
}
```

Then on `Form1` you can attach an event handler:

```
Form2 other = new Form2();
other.Refresh += () => time_refresh();
other.Show();
```

Comment: Nice, clean, well said. :)

Answer (score 0):

you get that error because you didn't assign `form1` value.

you can, for example create a property on `form2`:

```
public Main_form_1 Form1 { get { return form1; } set { form1 = value; } }
```

and assign it from the `form1` on `form2` initialization:

```
// code from some form1 method
var form2 = new form2();
form2.Form1 = this;
form2.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the variable `form1` inside your Form2.
As is, it's a variable of type Main_form_1 having a null value (meaning that it is not assigned to any valid instance of Main_form_1)

The most obvious method is to pass the instance of the current `Main_form_1` when you create an instance of Form2.
For example, inside the current `Main_form_1` you create an instance of Form2.
At this point you pass the reference of the current Main_form_1

```
 Form2 f = new Form2(this);
```

and in the constructor of Form2

```
public Form2(Main_form_1 f)
{
   form1 = f;
}
```

now your instance of Form2 has a correct reference to the running `Main_form_1` and could call the `time_refresh()` method on the correct instance of Main_form_1

Answer (score 0):

you might want to set in the constructor of your form 2 the instance of form1 used

```
private Form1 _currentForm1;
Public Form2(Form1 currentForm1)
{
    _currentForm1 = currentForm1;
}
```

and in your Form1 (in the constructor for example)

```
private Form1 _thisForm1;
public Form1()
{
    _thisForm1 = this;
}

//in your method simply say
Form2 form2 = new Form2(_thisForm1)
```

this will allow you to use public methods from form1 in your form 2 code. While not having the problem to instantiate a new form1 as that won't be the form shown to the user.

Answer (score -1):

You have to instantiate a new instance of Form1.  Try declaring it like this:

`private Main_form_1 form1 = new Main_form_1();`

And then you can call `form1.time_refresh();`

Also, what you could do is have your Form2 require an instance of Form1.

```
public Main_form_1 _form1; // global variable
public Form2(Main_form_1 form1)
{
     _form1 = form1;
}
```

And from there you can call the functions and it should affect your original form.

Comment: Thanks it stops the error but the does not run the function :(

Comment: Well, technically it does run the function, just not on the proper instance of the form.